# x (delete character under cursor) not working when creating a shortcut

Tags: key-bindings

Yeah... let me explain.

So I have this text that has hyphens on some words at the end of the line to join words, like this:

```
hello, my na- 
me is bruh...
```

This is a scanned book with OCR, and on every line there's a trailing space.

So, what I wanna do is make a shortcut, or map a list of commands (normal mode commands? idk how they're called) to:

- search `- \n` (hyphen space newline) and then
- do `xxgJ` (delete two characters [the selected by the search, and the trailing space] and join the line without adding a space).

This:

```
map <C-`> /- \n<CR><bar>xxgJ
```

I'm aware I can also do `2x` instead of `xx`.

And, it didn't work.

Now, maybe `x` or `dl`, same thing according to `:help x`, doesn't work when mapping it, like sort of how you have to use `\r` when replacing instead of `\n` (weird btw...).

But I don't know.

In normal mode they work as expected.

```
/- \n
<hit enter>
xxgJ
```

But when mapping them, the part that's supossed to delete the character under the cursor (`x` or `dl`) doesn't work.

Please help. And sorry for the humongous post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do:

```
map <C-`> /- \n<CR>xxgJ
```

The right hand side term of a mapping is like a macro, a bare list of character that will be passed to Vim.

Since you have no need to type `|` to execute your action there are no need to insert `<bar>`.

Comment: I CANNOT BELIVE THE ANSWER WAS THAT SIMPLE... do you know why this is? Thank you very much.

Comment: The mapping string is executed as is. You would not need to type `|` and so you would not need to insert `<bar>` :-)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-)

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt Perhaps add the explanation about why `<bar>` is incorrect in your answer.

Comment: Also, why does \n not work when replacing? Why do we have to use \r? It's an unrelated question.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution is to use the [`:s`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#%3As) command to handle these cases, you can match the `- \n` snippet and just replace it by an empty string, which will also end up joining lines (since you're replacing the line break with an empty string.)

```
:%s/- \n//
```

Comment: Thank you! This is actually a better wway to do it...